# Globe with exposed inner layers

Tags: tikz-pgf

Basically, I want to make 3 concentric spheres with a portion of them being open (very similar to what is shown in the iamge).

I only know how to make concentric-like circles in Tikz, can someone help with making one similar to the image I posted?

Thanks!

[image]

Here is my starting code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\footnotesize
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (6,0);
%\coordinate (endt) at (12,0); 
%draw the line
\draw[-, very thick] (A) -- (C);
\fill (A) circle (3pt) node[left=2pt] {A}; 
\fill (B) circle (3pt)  node[above=2pt] {B}; 
\fill (C) circle (3pt) node[right=2pt] {C}; 
\shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (A) circle (4cm);
\draw[dashed] (2,4) arc (90:-90:2cm and 4cm);
\draw[thick] (2,4) arc (90:270:2cm and 4cm);
\draw[thick] (A) circle (4cm);
%smaller circle
\shade[ball color=blue!20!white,opacity=0.20] (A) circle (3cm); 
\draw[thick] (A) circle (3cm);
\draw[dashed] (2,3) arc (90:-90:1.5cm and 3cm); 
\draw[thick] (2,3) arc (90:270:1.5cm and 3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Visualization of spatial distribution of A, C, and \B.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, Ah! Good one!

Comment: Use something which can draw 3D. Why use a 2D tool for what looks like a 3D job? You can fake simple 3D. But you'll get much more impressive results from something else.